# How to take preference with virtual method overriding and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

So at the moment I have 3 classes. `Shape`, `Square`, `Triangle`. `Triangle` and `Square` inheriting from `Shape`. In `Shape` I have the virtual methods:

> ```
> virtual bool myMethod();
>
> virtual bool myMethod(Shape& sha);
> ```

And for example in `Triangle` I have:

> ```
> virtual bool myMethod(Square& sqa); 
>
> virtual bool myMethod(Shape& tri);
> ```

Now in my main method I have:

```
Shape* m[3];
m[0] = new Square;
m[1] = new Triangle;
m[2] = new Square;
cout << m[0]->myMethod(*m[1]);
cout << m[0]->myMethod(*m[2]);
```

When I call it in the first `cout`, it works fine and goes to the method with `(Shape& tri)`, but on the second one it also goes to the `(Shape& tri)` method. I understand why this is happening, but is there any way I can make it so it goes to the `(Square& squ)` method instead of `Shape`?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like an application of the visitor pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ selects the method to be called using overload resolution. Overload resolution is entirely based on the static type of the arguments. If the called overload is a `virtual` function it may be overridden in a derived class in which case the call is dispatch at run-time to the override.

As far as I can tell, you want the system to do a multiple dispatch based on the object and the argument type. C++ doesn't directly support multi dispatch but there are some ways to simulate it. To deal with the dispatch you want, can arrange your calls to find the appropriate override at run-time. One way to do so is to split the functions into multiple versions.

```
struct Square;
struct Triangle'
struct Circle;

struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() {}

    virtual bool doMethod(Square& s) { return doMethod(static_cast<Shape&>(s)); }
    virtual bool doMethod(Triangle& s) { return doMethod(static_cast<Shape&>(s)); }
    virtual bool doMethod{Circle& s) { return doMethod(static_cast<Shape&>(s)); }

    virtual bool doMethod(Shape&) = 0;
    virtual bool myMethod(Shape&) = 0;
};

struct Triangle: Shape {
    bool myMethod(Shape& other) { return other.doMethod(*this); }
    bool doMethod(Shape& other) { /* general case */ }
    bool doMethod(Square& other) { /* special case */ }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense. However with the code that you've given I'm having some trouble implementing it as Shape doesn't actually know about square/triangle as they're inheriting from Shape, so i'm unable to create those virtual methods.

Comment: @Niamh: If you can't forward declare the shapes needing special treatment, you'll need some other approach dealing with [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch): which one is most suitable to your needs depends on what you really want to do. There is no "good" solution: all have their drawbacks: the one posted requires knowledge of the types (i.e., it is closed) but is efficient; other approaches trade more flexibility for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i've had a look at some other methods and went with doing a simple if statement if (Circle* cir = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&aShape)) as shown on the multiple dispatch wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a feature that does not exist in the C++ language. In C++, dynamic dispatch occurs *only* from the caller, not on any of the arguments.

So when you call `myMethod(*m[2])`, `*m[2]` is a `Shape` so it will call `bool myMethod(Shape& )` since that's what overload resolution prefers.

Now, if you really want something special in the `Triangle/Square` case, you might want to look at double dispatch:

```
virtual bool Triangle::myMethod(Shape& shape) {
    return shape.myMethodImpl(*this);
}
```

That way, you can have:

```
virtual bool Square::myMethodImpl(Triangle& triangle) {
    // ...
}
```

Which can only be called via that 2nd dispatch.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll read up on double dispatch and how to implement it.